# How to avoid using two nested for-loops for two related DataTables

Tags: vb.net, performance, for-loop, optimization, datatable

Trying to avoid using two nested for loops in the below code but I can't seem to think of a way to join both DataTables without having to use two for loops. Note that both DataTables are dynamic that's why I couldn't solve the problem at the level of SQL Query.

The below DataTable gets all sections from the database. They are
limited in number but dynamic.

```
Dim dtSections As DataTable = HomeSections()
```

Looping through the sections and getting all related items for each section:

```
If dtSections.Rows.Count > 0 Then   
    For Each mySectionRow As DataRow In dtSections.Rows 
        Dim dtItems As DataTable = getItemsBySection(sectionId)
        If dtItems.Rows.Count > 0 Then
           For Each myItemRow As DataRow In dtItems.Rows
               'Some HTML population
           Next 
        End if
   Next 
End if
```

I was wondering what could be the best way to avoid using nested for loops when the values of the second DataTable depends on values of the first DataTable. I thought of using a DataSet but I don't think I can generate the second DataTable based on the results of the first one.

Should this problem be solved at the level of the code or at the level of SQL (Stored Procedure for example)?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid nested loops in the first place?

Comment: @jmcilhinney O(n) is better than O(n2). Trying to improve the TTFB.

Comment: How much data are we talking about?  *"Note that both DataTables are dynamic"*.  What does that even mean?

Comment: O(n)... How many records do you expect to process in your nested loops?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Less than 300 records.

Comment: @Arvo The sections are less than 10 and for each section, I might have around 20 to 30 items. So that would loop 200-300 times on average.

Comment: @jmcilhinney By dynamic I mean that the values are being fetched from the database.

Comment: *"So that would loop 200-300 times on average"*. And how long does that take?  What I'm getting at is, what is the point of trying to save a few milliseconds that the user won't even notice?

Comment: *"By dynamic I mean that the values are being fetched from the database"*.  So "dynamic" means retrieved from a database and that is a reason that you can't do this in SQL?  How does that make sense, given that the whole purpose of SQL is to retrieve data from a database?

Comment: I agree that there is no escape from having calls to SQL by using two nested-for loops but what can be done to enhance the performance. Table "sections" does not contain more than 20 records. Table "Items" can be greater than a million records. If table "items" was not big in size, I would have retreived all items and used LINQ expressions. But in my case, I want to get paged data rows. Like 20 rows/items for each section on every call.

Comment: You could easily create SQL procedure, which joins source tables, uses window functions for paging and returns just required data (for page) and nothing more.

Comment: @Arvo This is what is happening right now. On every loop, I am returning 20 rows from items table depending on the section. This is actually affecting the TTFB (~1000ms) and my target TTFB is something between 300ms-600ms. Another thing, I am just worried that using two for-loops I am creating more requests on every page_load (around 200 requests: 10 sections with 20 records returned from Items table on every loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can join two data tables using LINQ

```
Dim query = From mySectionRow  In dtSections
                    Join myItemRow  In dtItems
                    On mySectionRow!sectionId Equals myItemRow!sectionId
                    Select mySectionRow!sectionId, myItemRow!sectionId

For Each q In query
    'Some HTML population
Next
```

Comment: That works if I already have the dtItems DaTatable already filled, right?

Comment: Yes! Filled or not , it doesn't matter.

Comment: Items table might reach a million row and maybe more. Isn't it wrong to pull all data from the table? I'm pulling only 20 records for each section on every loop. I see what you suggested here (doing the join at the level of the code instead of SQL) but won't it be a problem as tabel size gets bigger?

Comment: If you might have datatables with a lot of rows, you should consider T-SQL solution.